# How to insert data in object type column in Postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, edb

```
CREATE TYPE dbobj_vry AS
(
    a character varying[]
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calender
(
    day_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    day_date dbobj_vry
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Try to insert data in Calendar table.

```
insert into calender values ('1',dbobj_vry [9,5]);
```

It is not working.

Error shown -
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 2:                          dbobj_vry [9,5]
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 89

Comment: "It's not working" is not a valid Postgres error message. The syntax to specify composite type values is [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html)

Comment: This looks like a really horrible design. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually just try to insert data in calendar tables. can't able to insert. pls suggest correct syntax.

Comment: The correct syntax is [the link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) from my first comment. That looks like a really horrible way to store a "calendar"